# Why SetUnhandledExceptionFilter cannot capture some exception but AddVectoredExceptionHandler can do

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, exception

I have experienced a problem that the function I passed to the [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) didn't get called when the exception code c0000374 raising. But it works fine with the exception code c0000005.
Then I tried to use the [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, and it didn't have the problem, the handler function get called correctly.

Is it the API bug? Can I use AddVectoredExceptionHandler instead of SetUnhandledExceptionFilter everywhere?

The both functions work correctly with

```
// Exception code c0000005
int* p1 = NULL;
*p1 = 99;
```

Only AddVectoredExceptionHandler can capture this exception. (To prove it doesn't depend on the runtime library, I raise the exception manually and it results the same.)

```
// Exception code c0000374
RaiseException(0xc0000374, 0, 0, NULL);
```

Test program.

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

LONG WINAPI VectoredExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("VectoredExceptionHandler.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    f << std::hex << pExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << std::endl;
    f.close();

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

LONG WINAPI TopLevelExceptionHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pExceptionInfo)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.open("TopLevelExceptionHandler.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    f << std::hex << pExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << std::endl;
    f.close();

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, VectoredExceptionHandler);
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(TopLevelExceptionHandler);

    // Exception code c0000374
    RaiseException(0xc0000374, 0, 0, NULL);     

    // Exception code c0000005
    // int* p1 = NULL;
    // *p1 = 99;        


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The names suggest that the difference is that `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` only gets called for unhandled exceptions. Have you considered the possibility that the C++ run-time library handles the other exception type internally?

Comment: @hvd I think that is possible. I will find a way to verify.

Answer (score 19):

It happens because of this code in MSVC CRT startup:

```
    /*
     * Enable app termination when heap corruption is detected on
     * Windows Vista and above. This is a no-op on down-level OS's
     * and enabled by default for 64-bit processes.
     */

    if (!_NoHeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption)
    {
        HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    }
```

If you want to disable it (**not** recommended), link `nohetoc.obj` to your program.

Comment: Note it doesn't seem possible to disable this now, and no `nohetoc.obj` ships with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 6):

The exception is actually caught directly at its source, in `RtlReportCriticalFailure`, called by the heap manager once heap corruption is detected. The SEH handler registered in this function calls `RtlReportException`, quickly followed by `NtTerminateProcess`.

I can only conclude that SEH handlers are avoided on purpose -- with the heap corrupted, the stack contents (and therefore SEH registrations) are suspect too; and the application can't reasonably recover from heap corruption anyway.

Comment: An application may not be able to recover from heap corruption. However, for diagnostic purposes, it is highly valuable to still write a minidump. In addition, 64-bit builds use table-based exception handling (vs. frame-based) anyway, so a corrupted heap and/or stack will not affect exception handling. I also don't follow your reasoning: You have followed the code down to the exception handler only to conclude that *"SEH handlers are avoided on purpose"*. That didn't quite make sense.