# Counterpart to glibc's backtrace() and backtrace_symbols() on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, backtrace

Glibc provides the very handy `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` functions, which can help getting the stack trace of the current function programmatically ([see here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Backtraces)).

Does the Windows API provide any similar functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the function [CaptureStackBackTrace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use [SymFromAddr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its counterparts to get meaningful symbol names.

Comment: Nice, thanks! This is almost exactly what I'm looking for. It would also be nice to be able to convert the addresses returned by that function into corresponding symbol names.

Comment: @Grigory That is what SymFromAddr() does.

Comment: Nvm, I think I found an example of how to do it in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467604/how-can-you-use-capturestackbacktrace-to-capture-the-exception-stack-not-the-ca