# VC++ stack trace does not resolve function names on production

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, stack-trace

I recently implemented stack trace logging using [boost's new stacktrace library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html):

```
int debugErrorCallback(int status, const char* func_name, const char* err_msg, const char* file_name, int line, void* userdata)
{
    boost::stacktrace::stacktrace stacktrace(4, 10); //skipped 4 frames include cv::error, this function and 2 in boost::stacktrace ctor
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::detail::to_string(stacktrace.as_vector().data(), 
                                                      stacktrace.size()) << std::endl;
}
```

Having tested it on my development machine with perfect results:

```
0# cv::arithm_op at d:\src\opencv_24\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1293
1# cv::addWeighted at d:\src\opencv_24\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:2127
2# MyApplication::myFunction at d:\src\path\to\my\file.cpp:226
3# MyApplication::myOtherFunction at d:\src\path\to\my\other_file.cpp:146
...
```

I deployed new application version to production. Unfortunately, on production machine stack frames in my module are only resolved to the module name:

```
0# cv::addWeighted in opencv_core2413
1# cv::addWeighted in opencv_core2413
2# 0x00007FF7D0A0B56B in MyApplication
3# 0x00007FF7D0A0B2ED in MyApplication
...
```

I have debugged boost implementation of `stacktrace` to find that the stack functions' addresses are retrieved with [`RtlCaptureStackBackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-rtlcapturestackbacktrace), which seems to be working fine. Function names are then retrieved in `boost::stacktrace::detail::to_string` -> `get_name_impl` function in frame_msvc.ipp file, which internally uses [`IDebugSymbols`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/dbgeng/nn-dbgeng-idebugsymbols) object from library Dbgeng. This interface declares a function [`IDebugSymbols::GetNameByOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsymbols-getnamebyoffset) which is supposed to retrieve function name in format: `Module!function`. Unfortunately, it only does so on my development environment, while only returning module name on production systems. It seems like it's unable to retrieve symbols data for some reason, despite having deployed the MyApplication.pdb file along with the application.

As you might have noticed, function name (without source file and line number, which I could live without) is retrieved for statically linked opencv library, but not for my own sources.

I could not find what are the requirements for this implementation to work. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work regardless of runtime system?

EDIT2:

It turns out that the source of the problem is in fact inability to load the .pdb file. For some reason `IDebugClient`, `IDebugControl` or `IDebugSymbols`, whichever is supposed to load the symbols file (the are created in sequence during initialization of `debugging_symbols` class that is used to retrieve symbols in `boost::stacktrace::detail::to_string`), only looks for the it in the location written in the "Debugger Directories" section of the executable header. This is the path that VS creates in during linking (I tested it by copying the file to the same path on remote system and only then it worked).

Is there a way to make it load .pdb file in the local directory of the executable? Or perhaps it is possible to save relative path for the symbols file in the executable header?

EDIT:
Adding MCVE:

```
#include "boost/stacktrace.hpp"
int main()
{
    boost::stacktrace::stacktrace stacktrace;
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::detail::to_string(stacktrace.as_vector().data(), stacktrace.size()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And linker options:

```
/OUT:"path\x64\Release\MiscTest.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"path\x64\Release\MiscTest.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG:FULL /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"path\x64\Release\MiscTest.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\MiscTest.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Does production version has debug information available (.pdb)?

Comment: @VTT yes, I will indicate it clearly in the question

Comment: What settings have been used to create the PDB file? Are you sure you got the right PDB file? AFAIR the default settings would be that you only got a PDB file for debug builds, which you presumably didn't push to production.

Comment: @MSalters I link release build with [`/DEBUG:FULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) switch to generate symbols file. The stacktrace with function names on my machine is generated by executing the exact same .exe with exact same .pdb in its location

Comment: TBH I'd run this under ProcMon and filter all file access of your process; I know that newer Visual Studio versions can distribute debug information over multiple files. It certainly looks like Production is missing some files in which Visual Studio placed essential information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the reason is that `IDebugSymbols` does not load symbol file located in the directory of the executable, but only the one saved in Portable Executable header (it worked when I copied the .pdb file into the same path as it is on my development system).

I worked around this issue by creating my own `IDebugSymbols` instance (I copied the code creating it from [frame_msvc.ipp](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/blob/7fedfa12654d18a9fa695de258763e93699c4636/include/boost/stacktrace/detail/frame_msvc.ipp#L118) `debugging_symbols::try_init_com`) and modifying the last line to add "." (current directory) to symbol search path with `IDebugSymbols::AppendSymbolPath`:

```
if (S_OK == iclient->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDebugSymbols), idebug.to_void_ptr_ptr()))
    idebug->AppendSymbolPath(".");
```

This needs to be done only once during the process lifetime - it appears that the symbols paths string (or the symbols themselves) is cached, but I could not find documentation confirming it. Alternatively, the existence of "." part in the path could be checked with `IDebugSymbols::GetSymbolPath` during every `debugging_symbols::try_init_com` call. I also tested that `IDebugSymbols::AppendSymbolPath` checks current paths string and does not append duplicates (again could not find documentation to back this up) so it might be enough to always just try to append the "." during object initialization.

Comment: 1. Is this really not documented anywhere, neither MSDN or Boost Stacktrace docs? 2. Any further evidence for the seemingly caching of debug symbols/paths?